# What is the recommended return value for a function that does not find what it's looking for?

Tags: javascript

If I have functions intended to find respectively a certain DOM node, or a certain object in an array of objects, or a number in a list of integers including zero and both positive and negative values, or a string from an array of strings -- in each of these cases, if the function finds no match, what should I return? `undefined` ? `false` ? Is there an established approach to that?

Comment: @zer00ne You can return anything and the function will end, why did you pick `false`?

Comment: @zer00ne The function actually returns an `undefined`, or `void 0` to be more specific, by default. In case of methods where you expect value, the usual way is to return a null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything that is not an array, I would go with `false` or `null` or `undefined`.

But for arrays, I would return empty array `[]` in order to be able to compose the function with other array prototype methods (filter, map, etc).

Comment: Your second paragraph highlights one of the reasons I hate the [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts hmm, I see, it returns `null` if there are no matches!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situation you may want to return -1 or an empty array. But typically you'd return simply null.

```
return null;
```

Comment: I agree. You can also see that in JS itself, for example `document.getElementById("non-existing-id")` will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the native javascript methods as examples. For instance:

Does your method normally return a string? In that case return `""` just like js methods do:

```js
let s = "123"
let sub =  s.substring(10)
console.log(typeof sub, sub)
```

Does it return an index from an sequence? Then `-1` is probably the best result so it matches `indexOf`.

Functions that search through containers and like `Array.find` return `undefined` -- that's probably a good model to follow. Unlike `null` it doesn't return "object" for `typeof`

The only reason to return `false` is if the method returns `true` on success. Like `Array.some()`.

DOM searches like `getElementById()` return `null` on failure.

It's hard to think of an example where there won't be a good model to follow from native javascript. This will make the code much easier to understand and allow educated guesses to generally work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another vote to the `return null` answer, for several reasons. This has several advantages.

One of them is that the JavaScript Engine can optimize your code by assuming that you'll always return the same *shape* of the object. Returning `null` retains this shape.

Say you always return an item you found by given params. So it's a type `{ x: number }`. JIT compilers can assume that and have a version of your code directly in machine code (or close to it), saying "it's always a `{ x: number }`". But if you now sometimes throw a `return false` in, the optimization is not valid, because it reads as "this function returns mostly a `{ x: number }`, except sometimes, when it returns a boolean". Similar for `undefined`.

But a null can be also an instance of `{ x: number }`, it's just a null-instance of it.

Now the second reason, people are using typed systems more and more nowadays - think TypeScript and Flow. In such typed systems, your linters might also point this out: "hey, you're always returning a `{ x: number }`, but here a boolean, stop that!" And then your IDE red-underlines the `return false` part, and you have to change the return type annotation to `<any>` and your whole day is ruined.

But if it was a null, it would not have complained. So I suggest that you return a null for not found values.

P.S. Except, of course, for array-returning methods - go with an empty array, as the examples above demonstrate, if you expect chaining.

Comment: Great answer covering performance!